# Angular calls random services! Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Take a look at the following code.

**Main App:**

```
(function (){
   var app = angular.module("myApp",["aSubApp","anotherSubApp"]);
   var aController = function($scope, subService){
     subService.childService();
    }

 aController.$inject = ["$scope","subService"];
 app.controller("testController",aController);

 app.service("parentService",function(){
    this.parentalService = function(){ alert("Parenting Services"); }
   });
})();
```

Now, the sub Modules...

**Sub Module 1:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var aSubApp = angular.module("aSubApp", []);

    var subService = function (parentService, anotherService) {
        this.childService = function () {
            alert("Can I call random services???. I Don't know if they exist");
            parentService.parentalService();
            // This doesn't call the service defined beneath.
            anotherService.aRandomService();
            alert("Looks like they do!.");
        }
    }
    var anotherService = function () {
        this.aRandomService = function () {
            alert("another random SubService!!!");

        }
    }
    aSubApp.service("anotherService", anotherService);
    subService.$inject = ["parentService", "anotherService"];
    aSubApp.service("subService", subService);
})();
```

**Sub Module2:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var anotherSubApp = angular.module("anotherSubApp", []);

    var anotherService = function () {
        this.aRandomService = function () {
            alert("A random SubService!!!");

        }
    }
    anotherSubApp.service("anotherService", anotherService);
})();
```

Why does the code in subService.childService work? Shouldn't it tell me that it doesn't know where parentService and anotherService are present, for injection? Since they aren't dependent modules? Is it a JS thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var app = angular.module("myApp",["aSubApp","anotherSubApp"]);
```

You are injecting `aSubApp` and `anotherSubApp` module in your main app, so the `dependent` services are also available to your `myApp`.

If you look at your `index.html` of your `myApp` Module, you would notice that all your JS files are included there `[subService,parentService,anotherService]`

Comment: "You are injecting aSubApp and anotherSubApp module in your main app, so the dependent services are also available to your myApp." - this I accept but why is 'anotherSubApp' available in 'aSubApp', this I can't fanthom!

Comment: @anchreg: because you have this in your aSubApp,     aSubApp.service("anotherService", anotherService); you are declaring another service here...

Comment: But, I meant the anotherService in my module aSubApp. The alert that I get is from the anotherService of anotherSubApp, which aSubApp doesn't know!

Comment: In your index.html it seems that your anotherSubApp module's anotherService over-rides the aSubApp anotherService... That's how the JS works... if you have two functions with same name, the second one gets preceded over the first one... as the latter one over-rides it... http://jsfiddle.net/Meligy/yuvrk/

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have only one ng-app in page. Think of it all as one big object. adding dependencies simply adds properties to that object. So the main object needs to include all the sub module properties for the app to use them . and there is only one main object used for the whole application.All those services, directives, controllers etc are all combined into the master app module now and you can use them anywhere.

**EX:**

Lets say you add any plugins such as ngTable in your app. It is accessible through out the app. Hence same is true for your sub modules services also.

Comment: I've modified the question now, Can you take a look at it?